# get Spotify Oauth in NextJS but doesn't work

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, next.js

I'm making some music website portfolio with Spotify, NextJS
and I want to make play music in this website, and need Spotify authenication for use it.
when I click Login-button and got 405 HTTP status.
I checked on postman and got same error.
I searched and it might be error on GET/POST issues but I can't handle where to fix it.

app/api/login code part

```
export async function LoginHandler (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  const CLIENT_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID;
  const scope =
    "user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state streaming";
  
  res.redirect(
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?"+
      qs.stringify({
        response_type: "code",
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: `${REDIRECT_URL}/api/callback`,
        state: state,
      })
  );
```

I use useRouter(next/navigation) to route it.

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          router.push("/api/login");
        }}
      >
```

and this one is get token code

```
export const getAccessTokenData = () => {
  return axios<AccessTokenData>({
    method: "POST",
    url: SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization:
        "Basic " +
        Buffer.from(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString("base64"),
    },
    data: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
    },
  });
};

export const getAuthorizationTokenData = (code: string) => {
  return axios<AuthorizationTokenData>({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' +
        Buffer.from(
          `${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`
        ).toString('base64'),
    },
    data: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL + '/api/callback',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

405 error means  invalid Authentication or wrong format send parameter.
Your getAuthorizationTokenData()'s data was Incorrect Request Format.

To send data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format of axios POST call, you should use the `URLSearchParams` class to construct the request body.

You need to understand Spotify "Authorization Code Flow"
More detail in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow)

[image]

Demo code implemented Spotify login and get access token by `Authorization Code Flow` and get specific playlist and shows songs. Using next.js.

##### File structure

I added three files from create next.js project
(index.tsx, callbacl.tsx and constant.ts)

```
npx create-next-app@latest my-spotify-app --typescript
```

You need to remove `./src/app/pages.tsx` file.

[image]

Save `index.tsx`

```
// pages/index.tsx
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { clientId, scope, redirectUri } from './constants';

const Home = ({ spotifyAuthUrl }: { spotifyAuthUrl: string }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Spotify Login</h1>
            <a href={spotifyAuthUrl}>Login with Spotify</a>
        </div>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    const encodeRedirectUri = encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);
    const spotifyAuthUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${encodeRedirectUri}&scope=${scope}`;
    return { props: { spotifyAuthUrl } };
};

export default Home;
```

Save `callback.tsx`

```js
// pages/callback.tsx
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import axios from 'axios';
import { clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, myPlaylistId } from './constants';

interface Track {
    track: {
        name: string;
        id: string;
    };
}

const Callback = ({ accessToken, playlistTracks }: { accessToken: string, playlistTracks: Track[] }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Spotify Playlist Tracks</h1>
            <p>Access Token: {accessToken}</p>
            <ul>
                {playlistTracks.map((track, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {track.track.name}
                        <br />
                        <iframe
                            src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${track.track.id}`}
                            width="300"
                            height="80"
                            allow="encrypted-media"
                        ></iframe>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
    const code = query.code as string;

    if (!code) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code,
                redirect_uri: redirectUri,
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
            }).toString(),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
            }
        );

        const accessToken = response.data.access_token;

        const playlistResponse = await axios.get(
            `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${myPlaylistId}/tracks`,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                },
            }
        );

        const playlistTracks: Track[] = playlistResponse.data.items;

        return { props: { accessToken, playlistTracks } };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return { props: { accessToken: '', playlistTracks: [] } };
    }
};

export default Callback;
```

Save `constans.ts`

```js
// constants.ts
export const clientId = '[your client id]';
export const clientSecret = '[your client secret]';
export const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'; // replace your redirect URI
export const myPlaylistId = '[your playlist id]';
export const scope = 'playlist-read-private user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state streaming'; // Add more scopes if needed
```

##### Install dependency

```
npm insatall axios
```

##### Run it

```
npm run dev
```

##### Access it

```
http:/localhost:3000
```

##### Result

[image]