# Spotify Web API returning 'Insufficient client scope.' despite full client scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, vercel

I have written a program that intends to add songs to my own spotify playlist.

The below is the auth code:

```js
const { SpotifyWebApi } = require('spotify-web-api-node');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/callback`,
  });

  const scopes = ['playlist-read-private', 'playlist-read-collaborative', 'playlist-modify-public', 'playlist-modify-private', 'user-read-playback-state', 'user-modify-playback-state', 'user-read-currently-playing', 'playlist-read-collaborative', 'user-read-playback-position', 'user-library-modify'];
  const authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, null);
  res.writeHead(302, { Location: authorizeURL });
  res.end();
};
```

While you'd think I'd only need playlist-modify-public and private, I included them all after testing to make sure. The /callback function returns the refresh token which I include in my code.

Yet, when I try `` await spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist(playlistId, [`spotify:track:${songId}`]); ``, I get the following error:
`"An error occurred while communicating with Spotify's Web API.\nDetails: Insufficient client scope."`

I don't see how I can have the incorrect client scope?? I've made sure the tokens are correct. I don't know what to do.

Comment: That's only the code that triggers the login flow, by sending the user to the login URL. Where is the code that handles the result?

Answer (score 0):

The `spotify-web-api-node` not fully support [`Authorization Code Flow`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow).

It means you need to provide a call back endpoint as a local server by express.

And request `code` and exchange into `access token`.

[image]

This tutorial code is best example from `spotify-web-api-node`

```
https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/examples/tutorial/00-get-access-token.js
```

##### Demo code

For adding song into your playlist

Save as `demo.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

const PORT = 3000;  // it need to match your REDIRECT URI's port
const CLIENT_ID = '<your client id>'
const CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client secret>'
const PLAYLIST_ID = '<your playlist id>'
const scopes = [
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-modify-private'
];

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    redirectUri: `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback`,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET
});

const app = express();

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes));
});

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
    const error = req.query.error;
    const code = req.query.code;
    const state = req.query.state;

    if (error) {
        console.error('Callback Error:', error);
        res.send(`Callback Error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }

    spotifyApi
        .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
        .then(data => {
            const access_token = data.body['access_token'];
            const refresh_token = data.body['refresh_token'];
            const expires_in = data.body['expires_in'];

            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

            spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID, [
                'spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh'  // Prelude for Piano No. 11 in F-Sharp Minor
            ])
            res.send('Success! You added a song into your playlist');

            setInterval(async () => {
                const data = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken();
                const access_token = data.body['access_token'];
                spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }, expires_in / 2 * 1000);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting Tokens:', error);
            res.send(`Error getting Tokens: ${error}`);
        });
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(
        `HTTP Server up. Now go to http://localhost:${PORT}/login in your browser.`
    )
);
```

##### How to get your configuration

```
https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard
```

[image]

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express spotify-web-api-node
```

##### Run it

```
node demo.js
```

##### Login by Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

Again the port number needs to match your configuration.

##### result

[image]

[image]

##### Similar implementation by Next.js

[get Spotify Oauth in NextJS but doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171779/get-spotify-oauth-in-nextjs-but-doesnt-work/78172994#78172994)